# updateTabItems in shinydashboard with actionLink

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I need to set up different links n my first panel to open the other panels    (`tabItem`) using `shinydashboard` and in addition of the sidebar `menuItem` . For this the function `updateTabItems` should do the job!

I have tried different options and look many times at the examples and answers on this subject - including [Linking to a tab or panel of a shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315485/linking-to-a-tab-or-panel-of-a-shiny-app) and [Set relative link / anchor in R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61760403/set-relative-link-anchor-in-r-shiny/62290996#62290996)

I can not figure out why the reprex below does not work (aka links are inactive)? -

Thanks in advance for the hint!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <-   tagList(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Reprex"),
    dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
        menuItem(" Story ", tabName = "Stories"),
        menuItem( "Categories", tabName = "categories" ),
        menuItem( "Origin", tabName = "origin")
        )
      ),
    dashboardBody(
      shinydashboard::tabItems(
        shinydashboard::tabItem(tabName = "Stories",
              tags$ol(tags$li( actionLink(inputId =  "linkcategories",
                                               label = "categories") ),
                      tags$li(  actionLink(inputId =  "linkorigin",
                                               label = "origin") )
                     ) ) ,
       shinydashboard::tabItem(tabName = "categories", " blablablablablablabla"),
       shinydashboard::tabItem(tabName = "origin",  "  blablablablablablabla")
        )
      )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ## Get links to tab
  observeEvent(input$linkcategories, {
    shinydashboard::updateTabItems(session,  "tabs", selected =  "categories")
  })
  observeEvent(input$linkorigin, {
    shinydashboard::updateTabItems(session,   "tabs", selected = "origin")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it!! Was missing

```
id = "tabs",
```

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <-   tagList(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Reprex"),
    dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
        id = "tabs", ## here!!!
        menuItem(" Story ", tabName = "Stories"),
        menuItem( "Categories", tabName = "categories" ),
        menuItem( "Origin", tabName = "origin")
        )
      ),
    dashboardBody(
      shinydashboard::tabItems(
        shinydashboard::tabItem(tabName = "Stories",
              tags$ol(tags$li( actionLink(inputId =  "linkcategories",
                                               label = "categories") ),
                      tags$li(  actionLink(inputId =  "linkorigin",
                                               label = "origin") )
                     ) ) ,
       shinydashboard::tabItem(tabName = "categories", " blablablablablablabla"),
       shinydashboard::tabItem(tabName = "origin",  "  blablablablablablabla")
        )
      )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ## Get links to tab
  observeEvent(input$linkcategories, {
    shinydashboard::updateTabItems(session,  "tabs", selected =  "categories")
  })
  observeEvent(input$linkorigin, {
    shinydashboard::updateTabItems(session,   "tabs", selected = "origin")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```